# spring boot tries to find EnableWebSecurity class in spite of its not included

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Spring boot tries to find `@EnableWebSecurity` class in spite of its not included.

I'm using `@SpringApplication` and `@EnableWebMvc` together. Could be the problem?

This is the stacktrace (only appears if I use debug level):

```
DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClasses.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:121) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:60) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:423) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.wallapop.web.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
.16:52:18.172 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:573) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:424) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) [spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.wallapop.web.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: What's the problem? The message says that it's just advisory, presumably because you only included part of the Spring Security support.

Comment: using mvn dependency:tree I didn't see anything about spring security so just I dont understand why spring boot is looking for

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot then why are you explicitly using `@EnableWebMvc`? But as mentioned before it is a informational message (it is logged at debug level and the message is also quite clearly indicating this).

Comment: I'm not asking this because is a blocking issue. I mean, it doesn't matter if is an information message, I just want understand the behavior of Spring boot. If it tries to find spring security, probably I'm doing something wrong, so I would like to know what is it.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. Spring Boot's auto-configuration contains lots of classes that use annotations that may not be on the classpath. Those classes are only "switched on" when the annotation is on the classpath. All that you're seeing in the debug logging is a side-effect of Spring Boot figuring this out as it determines what it should auto-configure.

Comment: Seems like is not an error in fact. Is the way of spring boot to determine your desired auto-config. I guess must be something like: "if loadClass not thrown an exception, then load configuration for this class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is benign, you can explicitly exclude specific auto-configurations by adding this along-side `@SpringApplication`:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ...})
```

I *think* that will prevent the message from appearing in the log.

Also, Boot will generate an auto-configuration report detailing why each `XxxAutoConfiguration` was or was not applied -- start the app with `--debug` or `-Ddebug`, or use the `/autoconfig` Actuator endpoint.

Good luck.